# mysql command to insert new rows between old rows

Tags: mysql

i have a table with much data in it. the id is set as a primary with AUTO_INCREMENT function. how can i insert a new row like

```
INSERT INTO `medikamente`(`id`, `Augmentin`, `Ciproxin`, `Klacid`, `Voltaren`, `Seractil`, `Mexalen`, `Aspirin`, `Thomapyrin`, `Esomeprazol`, `Omeprazol`, `Nexium`, `Pantoloc`, `Guttalax`, `indikator`, `indikator2`) 
VALUES (NULL,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','');
```

lets say between id 5 and id 6? i don't want to change the id's manualy to have a free row between that id's. how can i do that over an command? 
br

Comment: Do you understand the consequences of changing the primary  key of a table?  How will you handle the other tables referring to 'medikamente' ?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille i thought that the new row get the id 6 and the id6 would be 6+1 and all the other rows under the old id6 would get +1. probably its not the best id with auto inrement, but if you have another idea how to handle that it would be cool

Comment: Just ONE question : Why ??!! Why do you want to do that ? What's your intention behind that ? This makes absolutely no sense in database world.

Comment: Seriously consider whether this is really a good idea.

Comment: @Gosfly your right! i just want to have a struct version like a excel table, because it is easier to read that table. no other special reason. but i think i close it, because i could delete the id and export the hole file as text, where i could struct that so as in excel. after that i could implement it again in the database and set an id with autoincrement. that works faster for me. i found something like that UPDATE mytable SET id = id + 1 where id > 5 ORDER BY id ASC but i dont know how it works with autoincrement if you have the last id row set + 1

Comment: @EduardTester I suggest rather than trying to change your primary key you instead use a `sortOrder` column which you can use to sort the results for your CSV. Since this is not your primary key there's no harm in bulk updating it to make room for a new record( `UPDATE medikamente SET sortOrder = sortOrder + 1 WHERE sortOrder >= 6`) and references to the rows can remain untouched since it's only the front end presentation you're changing.

Comment: @EduardTester First, you would need to use "ORDER BY id DESC" in your update statement instead of "ASC", second, this won't cause any issue with your autoincrement id, it will only take your max id +1 even after incrementing your last id row. Howevor, as it has been suggested many times here, it is absolutely not recommanded !

Comment: thx @all. i will try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get free place in `id` sequence by query:

```
UPDATE medikamente SET id = id + 1 WHERE id > 5 ORDER BY id DESC;
```

After you can use id 6 for insert new row:

```
INSERT INTO `medikamente`(
    `id`, `Augmentin`, `Ciproxin`, `Klacid`, `Voltaren`, `Seractil`, `Mexalen`, `Aspirin`, `Thomapyrin`, `Esomeprazol`, `Omeprazol`, `Nexium`, `Pantoloc`, `Guttalax`, `indikator`, `indikator2`
) VALUES (
    6,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
);
```

Be carefully if you table have foreign keys.